# XE2 - Indy TCPServer: what is the best way to write and read a listview?

Tags: c++, sockets, c++builder, indy, tcpserver

I am working with IdTCPServer and its doing ok for a limited amount of time, I am afraid its about the thread management in the listview, since I am using a TTimer to process data atm. so I would like to know possible ways I can handle those connections to read and write, the server will work with manny connections(receiving, processing and sending data in real time).

Answer (score 1):

`TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component.  Any access to the UI **must** be synchronized with the main UI thread, such as with Indy's `TIdSync` or `TIdNotify` classes, or bad things can happen.  A `TTimer` in the main thread is an OK choice for accessing data, provided the data is being accessed in a thread-safe manner, such as with a mutex or critical section. But a timer is not necessarily the best choice.  It really depends on what your code actually needs to do with the data and the UI.  Without that information, it is hard to advise you what is the best approach to meet your needs.  There are many choices available.

Comment: thank you very much for the help, I ll start looking at it. if I may ask, do you know of any reference/book/sample, so I can get started?